# How to get count of rows in a Spark dataframe with condition?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So I have a Spark dataset `dataset` and I want to get the 'number of rows' that meet a specific criterion (of matching date).

What I did was - filter out rows(meeting the condition) into `df2` and then do `df2.count()`

```
val df2=dataset.filter(to_date(dataset("publish_date")) === to_date(date_add(current_date(), -2)))

val count = df2.count()
```

Is there any way to get this count directly, without eating up more memory to store `df2`, and not altering my original `dataset` in any way?

Comment: this looks very direct already. What's the problem with this approach?

Comment: Your approach is direct already. If your data source supports predicate pushdown then there will be no much memory issues also.

Comment: Yeah, I realized this is as direct as it can get. Thanks. Closing this...